# THREE JS how to detect if one object is facing a selected point

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I'm very new to THREE JS and I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours now, but how do I determine whether or not a mesh is facing a selected point? Essentially what I have is an RTS style game, where you can select a character and select where he moves to. Currently you can select the character and you can select and where you want it to move to on the map and it will start walking, however I can't figure out how to determine if it is facing the right direction. I don't want to use lookAt because I want the mesh to turn while it walks forward, and not do anything instantaneously.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution is to select arbitrary look vector

```
var lookVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
```

and when you need to do some check transform a copy of this vector with mesh matrix (make sure matrix is updated and count in the geometry transformations if you did any)

```
var direction = lookVector.clone().applyMatrix4(mesh.matrix);
var origin = mesh.boundingSphere.center;
var lookVectorAtThisTime = direction.sub(origin);
```

then calculate the angle to your point of interest

```
var vectorToPOI =  POI.sub(origin);
var angle = lookVectorAtThisTime.angleTo(vectorToPOI);
if(angle < minAngle)
{
  //looking at the point
}
```

you can also calculate your look vector directly from geometry or some other way origin vector can be something else than the center of the object, but this should get you on the right path..